# Post method in Python using requests

Tags: python, html, post, request, python-requests

I have simple form which accepts text and calls a php file abc.php through post method:

```
<form method='post' action="abc.php">
<input type="textarea" name="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

contents of abc.php

```
<?php
$msg=$_POST["text"];
print $msg;
?>
```

I wrote a python script for posting messages using requests library as follows:

```
import requests
keys={'text':'lol rofl'}
r=requests.post("http://127.0.0.1/abc.php/POST",params=keys)
print r.url
print r.text
```

I was getting the following output(error):

```
  http://localhost/abc.php/POST?text=lol+rofl

<b>notice</b>:undefined index;text in C:/xampp/htdocs/abc.php on line 2
```

**note**:form and abc.php works perfectly when run from the browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right parameter to use is `data`:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

```
Typically, you want to send some form-encoded data — much like an HTML form.
To do this, simply pass a dictionary to the data argument.
Your dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded
when the request is made:

>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

Comment: @btevfik: That is a `.get()` (GET request) call. For POST, use `data`.

Comment: why in the earth do they make them different

Comment: @btevfik Because GET parameters are completely different from POST data? A POST request can optionally specify GET parameters as well as POST data, though a GET request obviously cannot specify POST data. They're different things and used in different situations.